# Prepositional phrase Vs Direct object

Tags: objects

I have seen the rule put forward that

> We need a direct object to form a passive sentence.

The following sentences don't have direct objects according to some schools of thought, they have prepositional phrases. But are these sentences passivisible?

> He is playing with me ["with me"= prepositional phrase] no direct
>   object in this sentence
>
> John is sitting by me ["by me"= prepositional phrase] no DO in this
>   sentence
>
> I slept in the bed ["in the bed"= prepositional phrase] no DO in this
>   sentence
>
> Mary arrived at school ["at school"= prepositional phrase] no DO in
>   this sentence
>
> He fell on the ground ["on the ground"= prepositional phrase] no DO in
>   this sentence

There are questions I feel can't be asked in isolation:

> Can a prepositional phrase like these act like a direct object?
>
> Should it be called a direct object?
>
> Are there exceptional cases?
>
> How does all this bear upon passivisability?

I will be very grateful to you If you provide the reasonable answers of my questions.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Whoa, just **one** question per post.

Comment: And, **after** having done some background research to show.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of the question, namely that "*we need a direct object to form a passive sentence*" is not correct. Active sentences with prepositional phrases can indeed be converted into passives, such as in the first example:

> I am being played with (by him).

Google shows plenty of hits with the similar phrase "*You are being toyed with*".

In fact, all of the sentences listed can, in an exercise in syntax, be converted to the passive as follows:

> I am being sat by by him
>
> The bed was slept in by me
>
> School was arrived at by Mary
>
> The ground was fallen on by him

Whether such constructions are considered acceptable has a lot to do with why we use the passive in the first place. Clearly, the passive allows the speaker or writer to make a certain person or thing the subject of the discourse.

So, the active sentence:

> The decorators arrived at the school shortly before dawn

could in theory be converted to:

> The school was arrived at by the decorators shortly before dawn, and by late evening had been completely repainted

if we wish to make the school our focus, not the decorators.

No doubt the passive here would still be found questionable by some. And this may also have something to do with the greater acceptability of idiomatic *verb + prepositional phrases* in the passive. Compare the following two sentences:

> The room has been gone into many times today.
>
> This problem has been gone into many times.

The second sentence with its idiomatic use seems much more acceptable.

Comment: There is an introduction at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) {Prepositional passive}:
'It is also possible, in some cases, to promote the object of a preposition....' 'The prepositional passive is common especially in informal English. However some potential uses appear [to be regarded as being] grammatically unacceptable; compare the following examples given by Pullum:

Someone has slept in this bunk. → This bunk has been slept in. (fully acceptable)
Someone has slept above this bunk. → ??This bunk has been slept above. (barely acceptable)'....

Comment: More depth and further references can be found in [this article {from Stanford University?}](http://hpsg.stanford.edu/HPSG07/Abstracts/submission_37.pdf).

Comment: @Edwin. Thanks, the Stanford article is very informative on this issue.

Comment: There's also a pretty thorough treatment in [Analyzing Syntax and Semantics: A Self-instructional Approach for Teachers ...
 _Virginia A. Heidinger](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IIs3wjjkk4YC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=%22a+good+time+was+had+by+all%22++passive&source=bl&ots=ClhHzaIYCS&sig=V0gXIWLEDKJQHAgQbDtBCgAKz1k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VBOtVLyiG4bbat7lgNgH&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22a%20good%20time%20was%20had%20by%20all%22%20%20passive&f=false). PP 111-112 in particular look at some restrictions on passivisation.

Comment: I've just come across [The Prepositional Passive in English_ Elizabeth Couper-Kuhlen](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xcUaFFrrLzcC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22was+gone+through+by%22+passive&source=bl&ots=oxgMPDBvDd&sig=vZsOkEFAiFCVksU3Czyu3_Y9qHo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OBatVOm0NJPgaqL2gKAI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22was%20gone%20through%20by%22%20passive&f=false). It seems pretty comprehensive as regards which V + prep (as opposed to MWVs) undergo passivisation. ...

Comment: I'm still looking for a piece I've lost discussing the different acceptabilities of metaphorical / literal (or should that be more cohesive and idiomatic / less cohesive?) usages.

Comment: I've just been looking at _A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language_ (p1164) on this. It states: "_Notice that ambiguous combinations like arrive at take the passive only when the preposition is part of an idiom_". So _A conclusion was arrived at_ is acceptable, but _A station was arrived at_ is not. But the CGEL goes on to note that "_combinations of verb and prepositional phrase which are awkward in brief sentences can become more tolerable with an enlarged context_".

Answer (score 0):

Addressing an underlying assumption in your fourth question (but with obvious overlaps to the others) I'd argue that simplistic views on what a 'direct object' should be considered as being are ill thought out and can soon lead to confusion.

In [The Passive and the Notion of Transitivity](http://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/res/article/view/4578)
Monique De Mattia-Viviès argues that 'passivization can be better accounted for when the phenomenon of transitivity, on which it is based, is defined on semantic [rather than syntactic] grounds.'

She writes: (slightly modified, & augmented)

> The passive is traditionally described as being based on the
>   phenomenon of *syntactic* transitivity. If the verb is followed by an
>   object complement, then the utterance can be passivized. Quirk et al.
>   (1985, pp. 159-171), and Huddleston & Pullum (2002, p. 1431) for
>   instance, underline that transitive verb sentences can be either
>   active or passive, that ‘Most verbs taking just one object permit
>   passivation:
>
> The hail damaged the car.
>
> The car was damaged by the hail.’
>
> They add that in addition to copula (he is at home) and intransitive
>   verbs (he is running), which having no object cannot take the passive,
>   a closed category of verbs or verbal phrases, which are most of the
>   time transitive verbs used statively or stative verbs, do not occur in
>   the passive:
>
> resemble / look like / take after someone ; suit / fit / become; have
>   / possess / lack; number / hold; mean; mind; boast; befall ;fail (let
>   down); cost / weigh; marry / meet; agree with:
>
> 1. They have a nice house.
> 2. He lacks confidence.
> 3. The auditorium holds 1500 people.
> 4. The dress becomes you.
> 5. John resembles his father.
> 6. His son took after him.
> 7. Will that suit you ?
> 8. The coat does not fit you.
> 9. This resort boasts the best beaches on the east coast.
> 10. He weighs a lot.
> 11. The enemy numbered over 20,000.
> 12. Three squared equals nine.
> 13. I don’t think they mind your criticism.
> 14. A strange adventure befell him.
> 15. He failed her. (= ‘he let her down’.)
> 16. John married her in June.
> 17. I met John in the street.
> 18. Mary agreed with Paul.
>
> These verbs can be divided into two sets: Resemble, have, mean, mind,
>   fit, cost, weigh, measure, lack, hold, etc. (set 1) Marry, meet (set
>   2) As the examples below show, these verbs permit passivization in one
>   of their senses, when the subject of the active is agentive or partly
>   agentive, i.e. when they refer to a process (set 1) and/or when they
>   cease to be reciprocal (set 2):
>
> 1. John has a book. *a book is had (by John). I’ve been had again. (They had me again.). A good time was had by all. (We all had a good
>      time.)
> 2. The suit fits me. *I’m fitted by this suit. I was fitted by the tailor. (The tailor fitted me.)
> 3. The car weighs two tons. *Two tons are weighed by this car. The letter was weighed by John. (John weighed the letter.)
> 4. The patio measures just 7 feet across. *Just 7 feet across is/are measured by the patio. The level of anticoagulant in the blood, which
>      is measured by a number called the INR, is hard to control. (A number
>      called INR measures the level of anticoagulant in the blood.)
> 5. This auditorium holds 500 people. *500 people are held by this auditorium. The cup was held by the winner. (The winner held the cup.)
> 6. Mary married John. *John was married by Mary. John was married by the preacher. (The preacher married John.)
> 7. Mary met John purely by chance in the street. *John was met by Mary purely by chance in the street. John was met by Mary at the station. (The meeting was scheduled.)
>      (John met Mary at the station.) His demands were met.

The conclusion she goes on to draw is not codifiable as a simple purely syntactically-based rule:

> **Conclusion**: with intransitive verbs, especially when there is no cognitive presupposition, the passive is possible if the NP included
>   in the adjunct of the active is affected in some way, and if the
>   subject (which becomes the agent by-phrase) conveys a lot of
>   information.
>
> This also affects transitive verbs: the agent by-phrase, when present,
>   is always rhematic, and is sometimes obligatory for the sentence to be
>   grammatically correct, otherwise the sentence does not convey enough
>   information....

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth, I did not get what you really want to say as a conclusion of this discussion, please elaborate a bit in simple words. Thanks

Comment: Before you start deciding whether something that looks like an S-V-DO sentence passivises, you have to decide whether it really makes sense to treat it as an S-V-DO sentence. The whale weighed a ton. They fought tooth and nail. He seems a nice man. The euphorbia resembled a cactus. The model had its original box. The outlaw broke jail. The shed caught fire. The boy trod water. Even if a true S-V-DO structure seems a reasonable analysis, eg I met John (by chance), passivisation is sometimes unacceptable (*John was met by me (by chance). //

Comment: Going on to address verb + PP constructions, the fact that 'This bed was slept in by the young Churchill' sounds acceptable, but 'This bed was slept above by the young Churchill' (think 'bunk') and 'This chair was rested in by Churchill' don't, shows that passivisability is very complex if not impossible to explain.